# Can I install PHP, even though I'm having problem with installing MySQL?

Tags: software-installation, php, lamp

I'm having **problem with installing MySQL. Can I install PHP despite that?**

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191354/problem-installing-mysql-lamp) is the problem with MySQL installation. (I ran out of room for adding information to that Question.)

Comment: yes you can. PHP can be installed without the need to install the other

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen: Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, PHP can be installed regardless of problems with MySQL installation.